# Creating a method with a Set collection argument that contains objects that are typed

Tags: java, generics

I need to transform the validation results of the form, which are represented by the `java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO>>`, where `dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO` is one of my forms that requires validation. For this I have created some method

```
public static void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<RegisterFormDTO>> validates) {
  ...
}
```

which, in fact, produces transformations. But, the problem is that besides `RegisterFormDTO`, I have many other different forms, and I would like to make one universal method that would transform validation results for all of them, especially since working with the form itself inside the method is not implied. The forms themselves do not extends from any other class, that is, just Object, and it would be logical to do so:

```
public static void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validates) {
  ...
}
```

but, for some reason, it does not roll, it returns an error: `java: incompatible types: java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<dox.web.dto.RegisterFormDTO>> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<java.lang.Object>>`. I have already tried and so `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Object>>`, which is the same, and so `Set<ConstraintViolation<? super Object>>`. All this is not rolling. As a result, it turns out that I create the same method for each form, differing only in the type in the method argument.
Can someone tell me how to make the method universal for all forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
public static <T> void process(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validates) {
...
}
```